# How to add numeric labels to a vector

Tags: r, tags

I was wondering how I could tag the number in a data set. To illustrate, here is what I get:

```
> U
     [,1]
[1,] 5.019720
[2,] 3.849288
[3,] 3.434410
[4,] 3.418294
[5,] 3.723506
[6,] 3.108474
[7,] 2.534136
```

but what I want is,

```
      1        2        3        4        5 
5.019765 3.849315 3.434434 3.418317 3.723531 
   6        7 
3.108500 2.534188
```

Comment: Is `U[,1]` what you need?

Comment: The output must be the same as the output above. None of these two give the output desired. Anything else please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you want to construct a named vector.  One easy way of doing this is to use `setNames()`:

```
x <- runif(5)
x
[1] 0.1350252 0.6986387 0.9814024 0.1204727 0.2901325
```

Now add the names:

```
setNames(x, 1:5)
        1         2         3         4         5 
0.1350252 0.6986387 0.9814024 0.1204727 0.2901325
```

---

This is, of course, equivalent to:

```
names(x) <- 1:5
x
        1         2         3         4         5 
0.1350252 0.6986387 0.9814024 0.1204727 0.2901325
```

Comment: Thank you Andrie. This is exactly what I was after

Comment: @Andrie, why `setNames()` and not just `names()`? (`names(x) <- 1:5`). The way I've always assumed `setNames()` was designed to be used was more in the example of `y <- setNames(runif(5), 1:5)`, where the names are assigned in the same line that the data are generated.

Comment: @AnandaMahto You are quite correct - these are equivalent.  It's just habit, I suppose.  Once I discovered `setNames()` I find I use it almost all the time because it saves typing.

Answer (score 3):

Andrie beat me and his way is superior but here's another approach (this shows how to turn the matrix object [with dimensions] you have into a vector):

```
U <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol=1)
U2 <- c(U)
names(U2) <- 1:length(U2)
U2
```

Giving:

```
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
-1.081053 -0.122568  1.650224 -2.217643  2.018205  1.451843
```